# How can I /testfor a specific player in a certain radius of the command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use command blocks to detect a specific player within a certain radius of the command?

I can detect a specific player, or a player within a certain radius, but not both.

Comment: Hi Ethan, what's the command(s) you've got so far? If you show us your work, we'll be able to help figure out what's going wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple arguments by separating them with commas.  Enter the following command into a command block:

`/testfor @a[name=<name>,r=<radius>]`, where `<name>` is a player's username and `<radius>` is the circular distance around the block.

You could put this command block on an infinite redstone loop to make it run over and over, all the time.

Comment: And to just detect any player in the radius leave out the name and just have the radius.  Example : /testfor @a[r=<radius>]  and he explained this well enough for you to get the rhythm of it.

Comment: and to limit the number of players to detect use @p[c=<countMax>]